# How can one include only specified labels from one file to another in NASM?

Tags: assembly, include, nasm

Let's suppose that you have a *library.asm* with a function that has a loop:

```
section   .text 

useful_func:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    loop0:
        ; Do useful stuff...
        jnz loop0

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

and a *main.asm* that includes the library and calls that function:

```
%include "library.asm"

section   .text
global    _start 

_start:
    ; Do stuff
    call useful_func
    ; Do more stuff
```

Of course, as a user of *library.asm*, you're not really interested in the label `loop0`, you're actually interested in `useful_func`. However, both labels are imported. So if you change your *main.asm* to:

```
%include "library.asm"

section   .text
global    _start 

_start:
    ; Do stuff
    loop0:
        call useful_func
        jnz loop0
    ; Do more stuff
```

You get an error, since the label `loop0` was defined twice.

So, is there any way to specify to NASM which labels are useful and should be exported/imported, and which ones shouldn't?

*Note: There is no necessity for the use of the `%include` command, it's simply the only way that I know to import from another file in NASM. If there is a better and more flexible command/way to do that, it's also appreciated.*

Comment: Use local labels.  https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html section 3.9

Comment: Another way to solve this is to mark the labels you want to export as `global` and then link the files together instead of relying on the `%include` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use local labels. nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html section 3.9

Local labels start with a `.`, and can be used as many times as you want on the code. Each local label is tied to the last non-local label. On this example:

```
1 label1:
2     .loop:            ; Implicitly label1.loop
3         ;stuff
4 label2:
5     .loop:            ; Implicitly label2.loop
6         ;other stuff
7 jmp .loop             ; Implicitly label2.loop
```

line `7` will jump to line `5`, since both of them are local and after `label2`. So you can change the labels that should not be external to local, and no conflict will happen:

*library.asm*

```
section   .text

useful_func:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    .loop0:                      ; Now local
        ; Do useful stuff...
        jnz .loop0

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

*main.asm*

```
%include "library.asm"

section   .text
global    _start       

_start:
    ; Do stuff
    .loop0:
        call useful_func
        jnz .loop0
    ; Do more stuff
```

---

> Another way to solve this is to mark the labels you want to export as global and then link the files together instead of relying on the %include directive.

If you don't mind changing your linkage and compilation (e.g. from `nasm -f elf64 main.asm && ld main.o -o main` to `nasm -f elf64 library.asm && nasm -f elf64 main.asm && ld library.asm main.o -o main`), then you can use the `global`/`extern` directives (read [this doc](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc6.html) sections 6.5 and 6.6 for more details) instead of `%include`.

Using this method, you will only export the *specific* labels declared with `global`/`extern`. So you can use it to avoid the conflict:

*library.asm*

```
global useful_func    ; Now global

section   .text

useful_func:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    loop0:
        ; Do useful stuff...
        jnz loop0

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

*main.asm*

```
extern useful_func    ; Now extern

section   .text
global    _start

_start:
    ; Do stuff
    loop0:
        call useful_func
        jnz loop0
    ; Do more stuff
```

*Note: Even if you decide to use this method, I'd suggest making your loops/conditionals local anyway, so you can reuse the labels.*

Comment: *it'll jump to the last label with this name on the code* - No, NASM local labels don't only look backward, and don't work that way.  They work by appending to the last non-local label, like `foo:`.  So `.loop` becomes `foo.loop` (and you can even refer to it from a different "scope").  You can't define `foo.loop` twice with two `.loop` labels, try your first example and you'll see NASM reject it.  (If you actually put a nop or something between the labels.  Defining the same label twice with the *same* address seems to be allowed.)

Comment: Example: of the error: https://godbolt.org/z/91MKET

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, thanks for the heads up. Updated the answer to correct it.

Comment: Looking at the rest of your answer now, [the `enter` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/enter) is invalid without operands.  Generally never use it, it's pretty slow.  Use `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp` instead of `enter 0,0` if you want to set up RBP as a frame pointer, otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: Also don't forget `global _start` - you need the linker to see it if `_start` isn't already at the top of the `.text` section.  (Which it won't be if you `%include` something else *before* it, or pass it as not the first `.o` to the linker.  You could move your `%include` to the end of the file, where any directives it contains like `section .rodata` won't affect the current state at the top of your code.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, the reason for the mistake is that I don't really use either `enter` or `leave`, just chose to use them there for the sake of simplicity. Same for `global _start`, didn't put it there for simplicity. Changed it to use them though, so at least it works as a MWE. Also, woudn't values in `.rodata` still be accessible even if they are at the bottom of the file?

Comment: My point was that if you left out the `section .text` after the `%include`, it would matter what section the other file last switched to.  But you do have that, so that downside doesn't really apply.  (And the file being included has to make sure it doesn't assume a current section.)  If you wanted your `%include` to `%define` any macros, you would want to include it first.  And BTW, any label in any section is accessible from any other section, regardless of order they appear in; that's not a concern.  It's common style to put data sections after code.

Comment: And BTW, `leave` is fine; GCC uses it.  Only `enter` is super-slow.  But you can just `pop rbp` if RSP is still pointing at the saved RBP, no need for `mov rsp,rbp`